# ORACLE SQL updating left table from right table using bridge table

Tags: sql, oracle

This is a why-oh-why moment for me. I have a many-to-many relationship between tables A and B. Two columns in A need to be updated with two columns from B based on where the IDs match in bridge table C.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Every script I've tried throws an error "single row query returns multiple rows".

[image]

Desired result is Reports.BU, Reports.AA = Assets.BU, Assets.AA where they match in Bridge. This is as far as I've gotten at this point.

```
UPDATE Reports 
SET (BU, AA) = (SELECT BU, AA 
                FROM (SELECT Bridge.Report.report_id,
                             Bridge.asset_id, 
                             Assets.BU, 
                             Assets.AA, 
                             MAX(Bridge.asset_id) 
                      FROM Bridge 
                      JOIN Asset
                        ON Asset.asset_id = Bridge.asset_id 
                      group by bridge.report_id, 
                               Bridge.asset_id, 
                               Asset.BU, 
                               Asset.AA) 
                WHERE report_id = Reports.report_id);
```

Comment: Sample data and the required output would help.

Comment: A minimal reproducible example would be very helpful.   From a requirements standpoint, if there is a many-to-many relationship between A and B, how do you know which row in B to use to update a particular row in A?  I assume the error you're getting is because you haven't defined that rule.

Comment: You approach is *legal* in two tables related `1:1`, you *may* do so in `1:n` tables which will lead to *denormalization* but will work. What do you expect to do in `m:n` tables? You must somehow turn it back to `1:n` saying I'll take only the *first* value from `A` ...